# Modifying a string in resource of an exe

Tags: delphi, api, resources

How do I modify `buffer` in following code then save the changes in resource of the executable? I'm looking for something like `SetString(handle,index,buffer,size)`.

```
var
  hExe : Cardinal;
  buffer : array [0..4097] of ansichar;
begin
  hExe:=LoadLibraryEx(PAnsiChar(Edit2.Text),0,LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);
  LoadString(hExe,65300,buffer,SizeOf(buffer));
  ShowMessage(buffer);
  //need to modify buffer here then I'll unload the resources..
end;
```

**Update:** Here's my attempt on UpdateResource

```
var
  hEXE: DWORD;
  pData: PAnsiChar;
begin
  pData := PAnsiChar(Edit1.Text);
  hEXE := BeginUpdateResource(pchar(edit2.text), FALSE);
  if hEXE <> 0 then
  begin
    UpdateResource(hEXE, RT_string, MAKEINTRESOURCE(4082), LANG_NEUTRAL,
      @pData, Length(pData)); //if i change 4082 to 65300 it creates another key like 4082
    EndUpdateResource(hEXE, FALSE);
  end;
```

This code messes up the whole 4082 content. The problem is item named 4082 in RT_STRING is group of strings. When I open the exe in a resource editor, click string table then 4082 the result is:

```
STRINGTABLE
LANGUAGE LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_NEUTRAL
{
65296,  "Unicode"
65297,  "Big Endian Unicode"
65298,  "UTF-8"
65299,  "UTF-7"
65300,  "ABCDE12345"
}
```

So I either need to parse the string group or I need an API to set modify string with the index 65300 in the group. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found [the answer](http://harryfin.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!31E57C5D97ECDF5!443.entry) using Google. ([English translation from Chinese](http://translate.google.com/translate?js=y&u=http%3A%2F%2Fharryfin.spaces.live.com%2Fblog%2Fcns!31E57C5D97ECDF5!443.entry&sl=zh-CN&tl=en)) Thanks anyways everyone!

```
procedure UpdateResString(AFileName, ANewString: string; AStringIdent: Integer);
  procedure WriteToArray(AArray: TByteDynArray; AData: Word; var APos: Integer);
  begin
    AArray[APos] := Lo(AData);
    AArray[APos + 1] := Hi(AData);
    Inc(APos, 2);
  end;

  function ReadFromArray(AArray: TByteDynArray; APos: Integer): Word;
  begin
    Result := AArray[APos] + AArray[APos + 1] * 16;
  end;

var
  hModule, hResInfo, hUpdate: THandle;
  ResData, TempData: TByteDynArray;
  wsNewString: WideString;
  iSection, iIndexInSection: Integer;
  i, iLen, iSkip, iPos: Integer;
begin
  hModule := LoadLibrary(PChar(AFileName));
  if hModule = 0 then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('file %s failed to load.', [AFileName]);

  // Calculate the resource string area and the string index in that area
  iSection := AStringIdent div 16 + 1;
  iIndexInSection := AStringIdent mod 16;

  // If the resource already exists, then read it out of the original data
  hResInfo := FindResource(hModule, MakeIntResource(iSection), RT_STRING);
  if hResInfo <> 0 then
  begin
    iLen := SizeOfResource(hModule, hResInfo);
    SetLength(ResData, iLen);
    CopyMemory(ResData, LockResource(LoadResource(hModule, hResInfo)), iLen);
  end;
  // Should first close the file, and then update
  FreeLibrary(hModule);
  // Calculate the new data is written to location
  wsNewString := WideString(ANewString);
  iLen := Length(wsNewString);
  iPos := 0;
  for i := 0 to iIndexInSection do
  begin
    if iPos > High(ResData) then
      SetLength(ResData, iPos + 2);
    if i <> iIndexInSection then
    begin
      iSkip := (ReadFromArray(ResData, iPos) + 1) * 2;
      Inc(iPos, iSkip);
    end;
  end;

  // Delete the original data and the data behind the temporary
  // storage of data to be added
  iSkip := (ReadFromArray(ResData, iPos) + 1) * 2;
  TempData := Copy(ResData, iPos + iSkip, Length(ResData) - iSkip);
  SetLength(ResData, iPos);
  SetLength(ResData, iPos + (iLen + 1) * 2 + Length(TempData));

  // Write new data
  WriteToArray(ResData, iLen, iPos);
  for i := 1 to iLen do
    WriteToArray(ResData, Ord(wsNewString[i]), iPos);
  // Write back to the original data
  for i := 0 to High(TempData) do
    ResData[iPos + i] := TempData[i];

  // Write the data back to file
  hUpdate := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(AFileName), False);
  if hUpdate = 0 then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt(
      'cannot write file %s. Please check whether it is open or set read-only.',
      [AFileName]);

  UpdateResource(hUpdate, RT_STRING, MakeIntResource(iSection), LANG_NEUTRAL,
    ResData, Length(ResData));
  EndUpdateResource(hUpdate, False);
end;
```

Comment: A user who has too little reputation to comment posted an answer saying that `Result := AArray[APos] + AArray[APos + 1] * 16;` should be `Result := AArray[APos] + AArray[APos + 1] * 16;`. I have no idea if that is correct or not; just putting it out there for you to see.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the [source code (Delphi 2006)](http://www.btinternet.com/~wilsoncpw/xnresourceeditor.zip) of the [XN Resource Editor](http://www.wilsonc.demon.co.uk/d10resourceeditor.htm) (is a free, powerful, fully featured resource editor and PE module explorer for Windows 98, Windows 2000 and Windows XP).

besides you should check the following functions

- [BeginUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648030%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [UpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648049%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [EndUpdateResource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648032%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Bye.

Comment: Requirements of XN Resource Editor doesn't compile with D2009 (gives left side unable to assign error - pngimage.pas ln 1845). I've tried with UpdateResource but I kept messing up other strings in same category.

Comment: you not need to compile your project, you can analyze the code directly.

Comment: Google is your friend http://www.google.com/#hl=en&safe=off&q=BeginUpdateResource++UpdateResource+EndUpdateResource+delphi+&aq=&aqi=&aq=f&aqi=&oq=BeginUpdateResource++UpdateResource+EndUpdateResource+delphi+&fp=3b1e5986dcbf14e4

Comment: True, but the code depends on requirements (a package called resourceutils from same person). I don't mean to be `give me the codes so I can copy-paste and use them`, but it's kind of overkill to analyze package that big for a simple use.

Answer (score 1):

There's an article talk about this on [Delphi3000](http://www.delphi3000.com):

[Resources inside .exe files](http://www.delphi3000.com/articles/article_3215.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to replace the entire group with a version that contains your modifications.  This isn't that difficult to parse, and you can take a few shortcuts.  Load everything into a tStringlist and then loop down the list until the string starts with '65300,'.  Perform your replacement and save the text portion of the stringlist as the replacement resource.