# Form resource not found after on-the-fly String-Resource translation

Tags: forms, delphi, winapi, resources, translation

I have a problem which occurs only in a very small customer range and I would like to ask if you might give me a hint where the problem might be. The program works for 98% of the customers. Alas, it is not possible that I work with the customers to debug the issue, because their knowledge of Windows and computers is very basic. It is also not possible that I send multiple versions of the product to them, since they don't even know how to install software (the admins do all the stuff).

First of all, I translate all `RT_STRING` resources on-the-fly, so that the language-switching in the program also affects hardcoded stuff like "Yes", "No", "Cancel" etc., which would only be possible by compiling 2 EXE files.

The code (I have tried to left away as much unnecessary stuff as possible, but since I don't know where the problem is, I provided as much details for the bug as possible):

**The ony-the-fly resource translation**

```
procedure TranslateResources;
var
  i: integer;
  s: string;
{$IF NOT Declared(FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED)}
const
  FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED = $2000;
{$IFEND}
begin
  // I copy all resources in a dummy DLL (without code), because
  // 1) The resources are the only thing we need when changing the resource module
  // 2) If the EXE code/debug sections are too long, BeginUpdateResource() will ruin the performance heavily
  FTempFile := IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(GetTempDirectory) + GetRandomString(8)+'.dll';

  // Transfers all resources from ParamStr(0) into the dummy DLL at FTempFile
  ReGenerateResourceFile(FTempFile);

  // if necessary, remove readonly flag
  SetFileAttributes(PChar(FTempFile), FILE_ATTRIBUTE_OFFLINE or
                                      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NOT_CONTENT_INDEXED or
                                      FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY );

  for i := 0 to Length(RTLResStringTranslationArray)-1 do
  begin
    s := Translate(RTLResStringTranslationArray[i].TranslationID);

    if s <> '' then
    begin
      // Translate the string
      UpdateResString(RTLResStringTranslationArray[i].ResStrDescriptor.Identifier, s);
    end;
  end;

  LoadNewResourceModule(FTempFile):
end;

procedure ReGenerateResourceFile(OutputFile: string);
var
  hUpd: Cardinal;
  rs: TResourceStream;
  fs: TFileStream;
begin
  // As template we use a dummy DLL which contains no code.
  // We will implement all resources from ParamStr(0) into it, before we translate the strings.
  rs := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, 'DUMMYDLL', 'DLL');
  fs := TFileStream.Create(OutputFile, fmCreate or fmOpenWrite);
  try
    fs.CopyFrom(rs, rs.Size)
  finally
    rs.Free;
    fs.Free;
  end;

  // Transfer resources from our EXE into the dummy DLL file
  hUpd := BeginUpdateResource(PChar(OutputFile), true);
  try
    EnumResourceTypes(hInstance, @_enumResTypesProc, hUpd);
  finally
    EndUpdateResource(hUpd, false)
  end;
end;

// This is based on reinit.pas from Borland's RichEdit example; slightly modified
function LoadNewResourceModule(PatchedFile: string): LongInt;
var
  NewInst: Longint;
  CurModule: PLibModule;
begin
  Result := 0;                                 

  // Win95: "Initialization routine failed"
  // NewInst := LoadLibrary(PChar(PatchedFile));

  NewInst := LoadLibraryEx(PChar(PatchedFile), 0, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE);

  CurModule := LibModuleList;
  Result := 0;
  while CurModule <> nil do
  begin
    if CurModule.Instance = HInstance then
    begin
      if CurModule.ResInstance <> CurModule.Instance then
        FreeLibrary(CurModule.ResInstance);

      // Win95: ERangeError
      CurModule^.ResInstance := NewInst;

      Result := NewInst;
      Exit;
    end;
    CurModule := CurModule.Next;
  end;
end;

// Based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498658/modifying-a-string-in-resource-of-an-exe
// Modified
procedure UpdateResString(const AStringIdent: Integer; const ANewString: WideString);
var
  ResData, TempData: TWordArray;
  iSection, iIndexInSection: Integer;
  i, iLen, iSkip, iPos: Integer;
begin
  // Calculate the resource string area and the string index in that area
  iSection := AStringIdent div 16 + 1;
  iIndexInSection := AStringIdent mod 16;

  ResData := ReadSectionCached(iSection);

  // Calculate the position of the string
  iLen := Length(ANewString);
  iPos := 0;
  for i := 0 to iIndexInSection do
  begin
    if iPos > High(ResData) then
    begin
      SetLength(ResData, iPos + 1);
      ResData[iPos] := 0;
    end;
    if i <> iIndexInSection then
    begin
      iSkip := ResData[iPos] + 1;
      Inc(iPos, iSkip);
    end;
  end;

  // Put data behind strings into TempData
  iSkip := 1{size} + ResData[iPos];
  SetLength(TempData, Length(ResData) - (iPos + iSkip));
  if Length(TempData) > 0 then
  begin
    CopyMemory(@TempData[0], @ResData[iPos + iSkip], Length(TempData)*SizeOf(TempData[0]));
  end;
  SetLength(ResData, iPos + (iLen + 1{size}) + Length(TempData));

  // Overwrite string
  ResData[iPos] := iLen;
  Inc(iPos);
  if iLen > 0 then
  begin
    CopyMemory(@ResData[iPos], @ANewString[1], iLen*SizeOf(ANewString[1]));
    Inc(iPos, iLen);
  end;

  // Append TempData after our new string
  if Length(TempData) > 0 then
  begin
    CopyMemory(@ResData[iPos], @TempData[0], Length(TempData)*SizeOf(TempData[0]));
  end;

  CacheSet(iSection, ResData);
end;

type
  TGlobalData = record
    GlobalPtr: Pointer;
    Length: integer;
  end;

function LoadResourcePtr(hModule: HMODULE; restype, resname: PChar; wIDLanguage: WORD): TGlobalData;
var
  hFind, hRes: THandle;
begin
  result.GlobalPtr := nil;
  result.Length    := -1;
  hFind := Windows.FindResourceEx(hModule, restype, resname, wIDLanguage);
  if hFind = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  hres := Windows.LoadResource(hModule, hFind);
  if hres = 0 then RaiseLastOSError;
  result.GlobalPtr := Windows.LockResource(hres);
  result.Length    := Windows.SizeofResource(hModule, hFind);
end;

function _enumResLangsProc(hmodule: HMODULE; restype, resname: PChar; wIDLanguage: WORD;
  lParam: LongInt): BOOL; stdcall;
var
  rs: TGlobalData;
begin
  rs := LoadResourcePtr(hmodule, restype, resname, wIDLanguage);
  UpdateResource(lParam, restype, resname, wIDLanguage, rs.GlobalPtr, rs.Length);
  result := true;
end;

function _enumResNamesProc(hmodule: HMODULE; restype, resname: PChar;
  lParam: LongInt): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  EnumResourceLanguages(hmodule, restype, resname, @_enumResLangsProc, lParam);
  result := true;
end;

function _enumResTypesProc(hmodule: HMODULE; restype: PChar;
  lParam: LongInt): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  EnumResourceNames(hmodule, restype, @_enumResNamesProc, lParam);
  result := true;
end;

{$R '..\dummydll\dummydll.RES'}
```

**Then I use a wait form:**

```
unit Wait;

interface

uses
  ...

type
  TWaitForm = class(TForm)
    ...
  end;

var
  WaitForm: TWaitForm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

...

end;
```

**The wait form will be called by dynamically showing the form:**

```
procedure ShowWaitForm;
begin
   ...

  { I use my own _CreateForm function because it solves many workarounds for
  juicy stuff like half-modal windows (which can be hidden without user action),
  miscellaneous deadlocks etc. and to allow the form to be shown in a shared PAS file
  without the requirement to add it to every DPR file where the WaitForm API is used. }
  WaitForm := _CreateForm(TWaitForm, {Application.MainForm}AParent) as TWaitForm;

  WaitForm.Show;

  ...
end;

function _CreateForm(InstanceClass: TCustomFormClass; AParent: TCustomForm): TCustomForm;
var
  LOwner: TComponent;
begin
  if Assigned(AParent) then
  begin
    LOwner := AParent;
  end
  else if Assigned(Application) then
  begin
    LOwner := Application;
  end
  else
  begin
    LOwner := nil;
  end;

  result := InstanceClass.Create(LOwner);
end;
```

The error message at 2% of the customers:

**Resource TWaitForm was not found**

However, other forms are working.

There are 2 theories I can think of:

1) Did the resource translation corrupt the DLL file / part of the `RCData` section? (Maybe a bug in the WinAPI's UpdateResource ?)

2) Is there a problem with the dynamic showing of the wait form (since other "static" forms are shown?)

Comment: 1) Are you sure you meant `RT_MESSAGETABLE` and not `RT_STRING`? Resourcestrings (e.g. Yes, No, Cancel, OK, etc) are stored in `RT_STRING` resources. The `RT_MESSAGETABLE` resource type is for event log messages. 2) You should check the `UpdateResource` return value. 3) I've had sporadic problems with `UpdateResource` but I have no explanation why.

Comment: Thanks, yes I meant `RT_STRING`. I will add a check for `UpdateResource`, and in case that it fails, I will simply cancel the translation process. I don't know if that would workaround this specific problem.

Comment: I wonder why somebody voted my question down. I know it is no SSCCE code, but SSCCE is not possible if I have no way to reproduce it, nor a hint where the problem might be.

Comment: I upvote question, from my point of the view no reason to downvote.